# How to open a bookmark without mouse in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox, opening a frequently-visited page without mouse is easy: click `⌘-L` (`Ctrl-L`) to go to the address bar, type a few characters, and omnibar will suggest you the page you're looking for.

But what about bookmarks? I have a lot of bookmarks (some grouped into folders, and some uncategorized), and I'd like to be able to quickly type a few characters and limit the omnibar suggestions to **bookmarks only** (because default omnibar suggestions are dominated by the browsing history)?

Comment: A [Super User](http://superuser.com/) question is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy! This is a somewhat hidden feature of Firefox: you can limit omnibar output to a certain type of suggestions by starting your search with a **special character**:

- `*` for bookmarks
- `%` for currently open tabs
- `#` for results that match the text in the title

The full list of special characters can be found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Location_Bar_search).

Answer (score 0):

You can type in a * after the keyword.

For example "recipes *"